# Nodemcu POST Response "-1"

Tags: nodemcu, web-server

**Nodemcu** device is returning **HTTP response -1** for a **POST** request on django rest api.

I tried the below http request to **Postman**, and it works perfectly fine.

http://localhost:8000/api/datalogs/?plant=http://localhost:8000/api/plants/1/&light=23&temperature=24&humidity=75&soil=Dry&moisture=787&remarks=/

This is my arduino post request:

```
if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin(host_url);

    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    httpCode = http.POST(postData);

    payload = http.getString();
    http.end();
}
```

The expected result is **200**, but I get **-1**. Can someone please explain?

Comment: the values of `host_url` and `postData` are not shown ... your code is sending unknown data .. therefore there is nothing to explain

Comment: you use the name "localhost" in the request from other device?

Comment: can you be more specific about the code on nodemcu side like what is the host_url and also postdata. At the same time update the code form Django side like what function is catching the http response from nodemcu.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I might be messing it with localhost, whereas my device has a different ip than my computer.. I should give it a try first [Juraj](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37622/juraj)

Comment: The host_url is `http://localhost:8000` and the postData is `"plant="+String(host)+"plants/1/&light="+String(lux)+"&temperature="+String(temperature)+"&humidity="+String(humidity)+"&soil="+mRes+"&moisture="+mVal+"&remarks=/";`
I think the issue might be **localhost** [jsotola](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/40318/jsotola)

Comment: So, I tried using **ip address**, also configured from **django settings**, works perfectly from my mobile device, Insomnia REST API client. But Nodemcu returns **301 Moved Permanently**.

Comment: if it returns 301 then only https is allowed so the url should use https://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution. It was a very simple mistake. The **NodeMCU IP** is not the same as the **Computer IP** that the server was running on.

I changed the **localhost** string with the IP of my pc, and it worked perfectly fine.